# Make MediaWiki not show the view history tab for unregistered users

Tags: mediawiki

I have a question. How do I make mediawiki not show the [view history] tab for unregister users? I know you can use css to do it:
in Mediawiki:common.css:

```
#ca-talk { display:none!important; }
#ca-history { display:none!important; }
```

but it's for everyone, even logged in users,so i want to have a way to make it just unregistered users.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, if you are running MediaWiki 1.18 or newer, you can add CSS that is only loaded for a specific user group. See the [manual page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUser_group_CSS_and_Javascript) for more information. So you should be able to add:

```
#ca-talk { display:none!important; }
#ca-history { display:none!important; }
```

to MediaWiki:Common.css and then add:

```
#ca-talk { display:block!important; }
#ca-history { display:block!important; }
```

to MediaWiki:Group-user.css. The second set of rules will only be applied to logged in users.