# How to hide Mediawiki History tab per group?

Tags: css, tabs, permissions, mediawiki, history

I I tried the proposed solution here : [Make MediaWiki not show the view history tab for unregistered users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806587/make-mediawiki-not-show-the-view-history-tab-for-unregistered-users) and it doesn't work for me.

I want to :

- Hide the history tab to registered users (group : user)
- Show the history tab to bureaucrats (group : bureaucrat)

As the bureaucrats are also registered users, using display:none doesn't work (it applies to all of them). How can I do it simply ?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page `[[MediaWiki:Group-user.css]]` you add this CSS:

```
#ca-history {
    display: none;
}
```

On the page `[[MediaWiki:Group-bureaucrat.css]]` you add this CSS:

```
#ca-history {
    display: block!important;
}
```

PS: According to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_group_CSS_and_Javascript `[[MediaWiki:Group-user.css]]` was only introduced in MediaWiki 1.23, so make sure you are at least using 1.23 :)

Comment: Hi, I already tried your solution. But as I said, if I add display:none to users and display:block to bureaucrats it doesnt work. How do you make it work ?

Comment: I just tested it myself and edited my answer. Please check if it works on your wiki as well :)

Comment: Thanks, it works as a charm :) in fact, I didn't use the !important tag, which is ... important for it to work ! And yes, I was using MW 1.26